# Dismissing a Loading Controller after http.get in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I've successfully implemented a loader, now I want to dismiss it when an http request returns successfully (and not after a specific timeout as can be set in the `duration` property of the Loading Controller). My http request is done in a service, and I try to dismiss the loader after subscribing to the service, but it doesn't work:

```
constructor(public LoadingController: LoadingController, public _service: SomeService) {
    ...
    this.loader = this.LoadingController.create({
        content: "Fetching Surveys..."
    });
    this.loader.present();
    ...
    this._service.getproducts()
        .subscribe(
            surveys => this.services = services, 
            () => this.loader.dismiss()
        );
}
```

Comment: Check what is the parameters in `subscribe` you should provide. In this sample, you close your `loader` only on error.

Comment: What parameters am I supposed to use, @DanilProkhorenko?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `complete` callback of `subscribe`, which will be executed on both `success` or `error` response from the service.

```
this._service.getproducts().subscribe(
        (surveys) => { this.services = services }, 
        (error) => { console.log(error) },
        () => {  
                // complete callback
                this.loader.dismiss() 
         }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't see how different this is from my implementation.

Comment: The second callback is an error callback where you are trying to dismiss loader. That won't be executed because that's reserved for error. You should have a third callback instead.